# Mudança de div atraves do JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Não estou conseguindo resolver um problema com Javascript, ainda sou muito leigo no assunto mais gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Eu tenho esse campo no site 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso criar um campo acima deles com a opção mesmo grau nos dois olhos,
consegui inserir um input acima deles com o prepend, porém não tenho ideia de como fazer a div olho esquerdo sumir e aproveitar a div olho direito para selecionar os dois graus. 
Eu usei esse código para inserir o input:

```
$('.colunaProduto .prodVariante').prepend('\
    <div class="mesmo-grau">\
        <input type="checkbox" name="mesmoGrau" id="mesmoGrau">\
        <label for="mesmoGrau">Mesmo grau nos dois olhos<label>\
    </div>'
);
```

algum tem alguma ideia do que eu posso fazer para esse tipo de alteração sem que eu tenha que acessar o código?

Comment: Se vc postar o código completo terá mais chances que alguém lhe ajude. Esse post vai ajudar vc em suas perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer isso